# Filter for multiple combinations with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform 2 different filters within the same line. As you can see below, I am looking for 1 of 3 numbers in one field and 1 of 2 numbers in a separate field. I don't believe this is written correctly as its still pulling more data for the 2nd set then the variables I indicated. I suspect its simply around my 'And' or the 'Or' but need some help.

```
For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
        ' Check cell of column 10 of row i and copy if matched
        If rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value = "303500" Or rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value = "604066" Or rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value = "613991" And rngData.Cells(i, 3).Value = "ACR/EM-1A" Or rngData.Cells(i, 3).Value = "ACR/EM-1D" Then
            ' Copy over to wsDalreq from row j
            j = j + 1
            rngData.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsTempinterior.Cells(j, 1)
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use parentheses to separate your two sets of `Or`ed tests.  Also consider using variables for performance/maintenance purposes

EDIT: split the cell checks into two separate `If` blocks

```
For i = 2 To rngData.Rows.Count
    ' Check cell of column 10 of row i and copy if matched
    val1 = rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value
    val2 = rngData.Cells(i, 3).Value

    If val1 = "303500" Or val1 = "604066" Or val1 = "613991" Then

       If val2 = "ACR/EM-1A" Or val2 = "ACR/EM-1D" Then

            ' Copy over to wsDalreq from row j
            j = j + 1
            rngData.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=wsTempinterior.Cells(j, 1)

        End If

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: I am running into an issue where its not bringing over any data. I suspect its because the 2nd set of data is formatted as text and the filter somehow isn't reading it correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Very difficult to say what the problem might be - you's have to check each cell independently to find out where the matches are missing.  See my edit above to split into two If blocks

Comment: Believe I just figured it out, there are a bunch of spaces after my text in each field. When I deleted them for a few lines they came over in my filter. What character can I use as a wildcard to pull anything over that starts with my two searches?

Comment: You can use `Like` but if you have spaces you'd better off using Trim to remove them before checking the value.  eg `val1=Trim(rngData.Cells(i, 10).Value)`